# Why do the ad boosts affect Time Warp profits so strangely?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

I was looking at the gold shop and noted that without my x4 ad boost, the profits from "1 time warp" on Earth were listed as $99.7 novemnonagintillion. After activating the boost, one would expect this to change to $398.8 novemnonagintillion, but instead it changed to $108.6 novemnonagintillion—roughly a 9% increase.

What's even stranger is that when I repeated this experiment on Mars, the listed totals had the correct ratio.

On Earth, I have:

- x42 multiplier
- 3 flux capitalors
- blue suit
- the Bonbon badge from Gates of Heck

On Mars, I have:

- green suit
- the Time Machine badge from An Excellent AdVenture 2017

Is there an explanation for this, or is it a bug?